# Poisson Distribution vs Gamma distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

Starting at 6 a.m., cars, buses, and motorcycles arrive at a highway toll booth according to
independent Poisson processes. Cars arrive about once every 5 minutes. Buses arrive about once
every 10 minutes. Motorcycles arrive about once every 30 minutes.
The question : Find the probability that the seventh motorcycle arrives within 45 minutes of the third motorcycle?
The answer is:

$$
P(S_7-S_3<45)=P(G<45)=pgamma(45,4,1/30), where G~Gamma(4,1/30)=0.066
$$
My question is why the solution is not a poisson solution?
$$
(_{45} = 4|_{+45} = 7) = (_{45} = 4|_ = 3)=(_{45} = 4)=0.047?
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Poisson calculation would work if stated correctly.  $N_{t}\sim\text{Pois}(\frac{t}{30})$  here

You want $P(N_{45} \ge 7-3) = 1- P(N_{45} \le 3)$: there may be $4$ *or more* motorcycles in the $45$ minutes  (your $0.047$ is for exactly $4$)

so you can find it in R with

```
1 - ppois(3, 45/30)
# 0.06564245
```

the same as `pgamma(45, 4, 1/30)`

Answer (score 0):

The Gamma distribution is the waiting time distribution time between $n$ arrivals in a Poisson process.